# How to embed a custom HTML inside CSHTML

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I want to embed custom HTML inside it. The custom html has such lines :

```
<li><a><img style="max-width:90px;" src="img/pic.png"> </a></li> 
<link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

These lines make error because the css and pic files are not loaded. How can I make that cshtml file load these files? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure img and css folders are in the same folder?

Comment: Use `@Url.Content` to return absolute path to CSS/image/JS files if you using Razor, e.g. `<li><a><img style="max-width:90px;" src="@Url.Content("~/img/pic.png")"></a></li> `.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it should work without that too

Comment: @Usman I agree it should work without `Url.Content`, but `Url.Content` ensures file path rendered properly based from hierarchical structure of project's root directory.